# Auto Logout in Silverlight

Tags: silverlight-4.0

I am working on a SL application, that uses WCF RIA services. I have to implement a Login Page, along with Auto Logout, if user remains idle for specified amoutn of time. Now since this is my first web based application. Am not sure how to Implement Auto Logout.

Answer (score 0):

check this..
http://forums.silverlight.net/t/220571.aspx/1?Auto%20Logout%20

http://developersvoice.com/silverlight-auto-logout-user-after-10-minutes-of-inactivity.html